# Как реализовать метки на сайте?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

Тупой и странный вопрос. Нужно создать обработку и создание меток на сайте наподобие как на этом сайте. Я просто понимаю примерно как оно должно работать. Пользователь вводит часть слова, я в таблице меток ищу похожие метки, и вывожу пользователю варианты, пользователь отмечает нужные и они с помощью jqvery добавляются на html страницу. Но хотелось бы увидеть пример, я что то сам не смог найти.
Может кто то что подскажет и поделиться ссылкой с примером.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ ?

Comment: @Lexx918 Принципе неплохой вариант, но может кто более изящный вариант предложит, просто тегов море будет и выпадающий список как то не пойдет, но спасибо за ссылку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю тут подойдет Chosen ( https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ ) посмотрите пример "Multiple Select". Даст вам минимум заморочек с XHR подгрузкой данных и тд, если меток, ну меньше пары сотен - для небольших проектов работает приемлемо.